# Assigning to a dynamically addressed property in TypeScript interface

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to access an object property dynamically from a variable which is a `keyof` of the object variable type. Example (same as [TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&module=1&strict=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLACYQDbDATwGEALCBAawCUB7Ad2QG8AoZV5ABQEYAuZEAVwC2AI2gBuFm3YAmXgGcwUUAHMJbDgGZ5ilRIC+TQwmogFychHxzeACgv5qMNJhx4ipCjVoBKANoBdZABeZF8AchkwgBpkCI0w-wkmGH4QBDBgE2RIBRs4XnQsXAISMio6b0ZJVns5ADoYaigAUURiO0tggD4q9XU4X3tAkIGhgH46sGoAZR0QZRtvCZ1BRerkPW9DAyA)):

```
interface FidelityCheckRow {
    P1: number;
    P2: string;
    P3: string;
}


const keys: (keyof FidelityCheckRow)[] = ['P2', 'P3'];

function test(a: FidelityCheckRow) {
    keys.forEach(key => {
        a[key] = a[key]?.toString()?.trim()
    })

}
```

When the base object interface contains properties of different types (not all strings), I get the following error:

`Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)`

What is illegal in this assignment? And how can I make TypeScript understand my intention?

P.S.
Actually I am going to iterate a subset of `string` properties, maybe this information can help figure out the proper way of doing the thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the type signature `(keyof FidelityCheckRow)[]` you specify that each `key` can be any of the keys of `FidelityCheckRow`, so also the one with a number value. Without the cast the type will be `string[]` which is also not what you want, but if you declare `keys` as a tuple by using `as const` the type of `key` will get narrowed down correctly:

```
interface FidelityCheckRow {
    P1: number;
    P2: string;
    P3: string;
}

const keys = ['P2', 'P3'] as const

function test(a: FidelityCheckRow) {
    keys.forEach(key => {
        a[key] = a[key]?.toString()?.trim()
    })
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&module=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLACYQDbDATwGEALCBAawCUB7Ad2QG8AoZV5ABQEYAuZEAVwC2AI2gBuFm3YAmXgGcwUUAHMJbDgGZ5ilRIC%20TJgmogFychHxzkAXmQBtAOQzHAGmTONjgLrI4141MwQxh%20EAQwYBNkSAUACjhedCxcAhIyKjoASkZJVgsrADoYaigAUURiOILbAD5c9XU4ewLfO2bWgH5CsGoAZR0QZTis7p1BEbzkPSymAyA)

**About validating the keys:**

Since we use `keys` as a tuple to preserve the exact literal types, we can't use a type signature to validate those keys, as the resulting type would no longer be specific. Incorrect keys will trigger errors on use though (e.g. at `a[key]`).

There are workarounds to make sure `keys` only has valid keys, for example by creating a generic type that constrains its parameter to an array of valid keys:

```
type AssertKeys<K extends ReadonlyArray<keyof FidelityCheckRow>> = never
```

You can use it by putting a dummy `Assertion` type near your keys definition and passing it the type of the keys tuple:

```
const badKeys = ['P2', 'P3', 'P4'] as const
type Assertion = AssertKeys<typeof badKeys>
// ERROR: ... Type '"P4"' is not assignable to type 'keyof FidelityCheckRow'.
```

Another option is to use a constructor function to create the keys, which is just an identity function that restricts its argument to valid key tuples:

```
const mkKeys = (ks: ReadonlyArray<keyof FidelityCheckRow>) => ks
```

If you use `mkKeys` to create the key tuple, any invalid keys will be flagged:

```
const mkKeys = <K extends ReadonlyArray<keyof FidelityCheckRow>>(ks: K) => ks

const goodKeys = mkKeys(['P2', 'P3']) // No error
const badKeys = mkKeys(['P2', 'P3', 'P4'])
// ERROR: Type '"P4"' is not assignable to type 'keyof FidelityCheckRow'.
```

And while we're at it, we might as well parameterize the constructor with the object type and the desired value type, so you can use it for other interfaces than `FidelityCheckRow`, and other value types than `string`:

```
type FilterKeysByValue<T, V> = keyof {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends V ? K : never]: never 
}
const mkKeys = <T, V>(ks: ReadonlyArray<FilterKeysByValue<T, V>>) => ks
```

The error messages are slightly less descriptive, but with the explicit type parameters around, just a squiggly is probably informative enough to see what's wrong:

```
const goodKeys = mkKeys<FidelityCheckRow, string>(['P2', 'P3']) // No error

const badKeys1 = mkKeys<FidelityCheckRow, string>(['P1', 'P2', 'P3'])
// ERROR: Type '"P1"' is not assignable to type '"P2" | "P3"'.

const badKeys2 = mkKeys<FidelityCheckRow, number>(['P1', 'P2', 'P3'])
// ERROR: Type '"P2"' is not assignable to type '"P1"'.
// ERROR: Type '"P3"' is not assignable to type '"P1"'.
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&module=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLACYQDbDATwGEALCBAawCUB7Ad2QG8AoZV5ABQEYAuZEAVwC2AI2gBuFm3YAmXgGcwUUAHMJbDgGZ5ilRIC+TJs1YJqIBcnIR8c5AF5kAbQDkM5wBpkrjc4C6yOFtTczBDVhh+EAQwYDNkSAUACjhedCxcAhIyKjoASkZJVisbADoYaigAUURiROL7AD4C9VY4R2L-BzaOgH4SsGoAZR0QZUTcvp1BccLkPVzJAwMjSQIABxQAQTk5aDAAaWs5AB595AgAD0gQDFtKCDgMM2x8TagoOHxj4uoYNEwcHgiKQKDRaA0mg4QBAAG7QMLIYIWYSPQ42exOVzSDxedg+TyuAAsfgCQTMCgR6y2Oz2sRAGO2uygByOxypv2QKIwaLkDUkAHp+chKpRKAB5Si8ErS5AAFXwGy8ACJ2ISlc5kMBbCBqGBSXJgMoQHBhNgUAN4gqUM4fn80oDMiCcrRnCUmMtjIjyXrBOQeRjjgA1dwNOpyXj3R7PV7vT7fawc+0ZYHZMENfJ2JrkOQIpF65TUajco4Y308xIuNwEvF+fKC5AAOWo53eFUkec5qJLDjLRwrWJx3kHqtrAqFIvFkrlVuVqvVmu1uv1huNpvNzapXlt-3SQKyoLorvdhk9m-Q2EgUB5ACF8IG4Nh+BBjrLPIHIZYE39PaxHGdQJ++AcrKpJyn+-iXNctzIIGyA9MgZy8NCcJQL4SGwtAyCLO23rIL26IOC+b6htmEYPE8IAvG8HxfOel43neD5PkRMEQhmWY5qwOEhMgBZFv6PZ+qySZ7k6YKeAoSijKGlbYtWPi+HWQpNi2UBtiYuFcjynClkJNjHCJjqpnQEkjMoMmuJww5ybiCkLKw9YThKvDyoqzgqpw85anwS6BAaRomma8QbjO7kyEqyAAD7ICqGjqm6XEaTxWlHNIuk8gZALJvuzqeAIIjQBZXDWcOdljsKorOdObkqtIXmLnqfkroF66WjVXDxeVTlTq51qxfVPmNTszVrsFbV9R1R4GEAA)

Comment: This approach seems clear, thanks. Is it possible to also make sure the spelling of the keys is proper? I mean, to force the intellilsense and refactoring in VSCode. Now the `keys` array is not related to the original `FidelityCheckRow` interface.

Comment: If you add missing keys you'll get a type error inside `test`. Flagging it at `keys` can't be done with a simple type signature, but there are some options. Let me add them to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, the constructor approach just works well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, first extract the string properties of type and then in forEach typescript detect the properties string.

For example:

```
interface FidelityCheckRow {
    P1: number;
    P2: string;
    P3: string;
}

type ExtractStringPropertyNames<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never
}[keyof T]

type STRING_KEYS = ExtractStringPropertyNames<FidelityCheckRow>

const keys: STRING_KEYS[] = ['P2', 'P3'];

function tests(a: FidelityCheckRow) {
    keys.forEach(key => {
        a[key] = a[key].toString().trim();
    });
}
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLACYQDbDATwGEALCBAawCUB7Ad2QG8AoZV5ABQEYAuZEAVwC2AI2gBuFm3YAmXgGcwUUAHMJbDgGZ5ilRIC+TJgQAOKAKIAPRYjABlHSGXso1U1AIA5OIIhyAPAAqAHzIALyMkqwA2gDSyKDI5BD41DDIAQC6vAGxGcgQVhAgGHLICkqOyAD8yHG8IBAAbtBMelFJKWmZhiYotgGUAJIeAOIA+jFmAJq2YciW1gh2Dk4ubp7evn7oWLgEJGRUdEGGCNQgConJcrz9Q6MT07ZReeFRAOQy7wA0yJ8a7wyEiYMH4ICWwHOyEgCjkAAo4Lwdjg8ERSBQaLQAJQRdQdOQAOhg1CgZkQxDhHTCIWY6jpbDg7WSr2QjI6GQJYGo9gqyjhWM5SkE-LUbD0WP0QA)

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was not exact: I'm not going to iterate all the `string` properties, but a subset of such. I can't figure out how to alter the code to accommodate this.